# Compare Values in Word Table Rows and Columns and Delete or Merge Cells

Tags: vba, ms-word

The problem that I have been given is to format a word table where multiple rows are merged based on a date value that is duplicated. In the sample below, column 1 displays duplicated date values and in column 2 is the corresponding text relating to that date:

01/03/2017  Perusing email from A
01/03/2017  Email to Subcommittee
01/03/2017  Perusing email from A
01/03/2017  Telephone call to Mr D
01/03/2017  Telephone call from Mr D
01/03/2017  Telephone call from Dr B

What I want to end up with is the following:

01/03/2017  Perusing email from A
            Email to Subcommittee
            Perusing email from A
            Telephone call to Mr D
            Telephone call from Mr D
            Telephone call from Dr B

That is, I want **one date** in column 1 and **merged text** in column 2. I couldn't find much help with coding in MS Word as it was more targetted towards MS Excel.

I know I can use:

```
If ActiveDocument.Tables.Count >= 1 Then 
   With ActiveDocument.Tables(1) 
     .Cell(Row:=1, Column:=1).Merge _ 
     MergeTo:=.Cell(Row:=1, Column:=2) 
     .Borders.Enable = False 
   End With 
End If
```

However, that is just a simple merge and I need something more complex based on the criteria I have mentioned above.

Hoping someone can assist and point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

In MS Word, once you merge rows you lose the ability to address rows in that table reliably. Once you merge columns, Word will not be able to respond correctly to the column numbers by which you address individual cells within that table. Therefore your plan won't work, at least not while using VBA.

Your task is terribly complicated because you try to modify data in situ. The better - and easier - way would be to re-write everything into a new table, perhaps one with only two columns, one for the date and the other for all the other text.

To bring this question to the point that it can be asked you should design the output table, make sure that your source table has no merged cells, the rules by which data are transferred, and a valiant effort to show that you tried to solve the problem on your own. :-)

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  I would dearly love to rewrite the code that produces the output but it is from a locked software program. The request to format the table is an afterthought from the user.  Because the output can be many pages long this was merely an attempt to save the editor to laboriously select, merge and delete at each change in the date field.  I will have a rethink at what I can do.